Python. Удаление несольких символов из строки
К примеру, есть строка:
stck = 'Stackoverflow', задача удалить из данной строки символы s,  s = 'owf' именно одной строкой s. Использование циклов или импортирование библиотек не приветствуется. Решение можно не самое эффективное, но самое простое.

Этот вопрос похож на: Необходимо очистить строку от посторонних символов. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

По условиям задачи подойдет решение с методом str.translate:
stck = 'Stackoverflow'
s = 'owf'

stck = stck.translate(str.maketrans("", "", s))
print(stck)  >>>  Stackverl

Более простое решение (метод str.replace более известен) будет всё же с циклом:
stck = 'Stackoverflow'
s = 'owf'

for ch in s:
    stck = stck.replace(ch, '')

print(stck)  >>>  Stackverl

Менее простое решение можно написать с re (стандартная библиотека Python) - через метод re.sub:
import re

stck = 'Stackoverflow'
s = 'owf'

mask = '[' + '|'.join(s) + ']'
stck = re.sub(mask, "" , stck)
print(stck)  >>>  Stackverl


Не самое красивое решение, но при помощи .replace и без использования цикла:
stck = 'Stackoverflow'
s = 'owf'
print(stck.replace(s[0], "").replace(s[1], "").replace(s[2], ""))

Вывод при запуске кода:
'Stackverl'


str_ = 'StackoveflowString'
s = 'owf'
print(''.join([i for i in str_ if i not in s]))

